# Paypal not auto returning to url after payment is made

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm running an ecommerce site using wordpress with woocommerce, and taking payment with paypal.

Once a customer has paid using paypal I need them to return to a specific url instantaneously. Customers currently have to wait 10 seconds before this can happen.

I have changed the settings in paypal to autoreturn the url, however this doesn't appear to have worked.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With Payments Standard, even with Auto-Return enabled, you still have to wait the 10 seconds (or so) for the redirect to occur.  This creates a problem where there is no guarantee the user will actually make it back there.

If you switch to Express Checkout instead the user will always end up back on your site.  Woo sells and Express Checkout plugin, but it's a little expensive in my opinion, and it's actually not very well integrated with PayPal, unfortunately.

As such, I developed my own version of a PayPal Woo extension that I've been using successfully.  I'm about to launch it as an open-source solution on Github.  If you want to [contact me directly](http://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/) I can give you an early copy that you install and use.